# Why does my ServerFault favicon sometimes turn into SuperUser?

Tags: bug, status-declined, favicon

I have links for StackOverflow, ServerFault, SuperUser and Meta next to each other on my Bookmark toolbar in Firefox (windows) 3.5.  Sometimes the favicon for ServerFault turns into the SuperUser icon (though the link is unchanged.  Maybe this belongs on SuperUser, rather than Meta, but it seems StackOverflow related since it doesn't happen to any other icons.

Answer (score 5):

When I used Firefox in the past I had noticed this would happen occasionally. I never quite isolated down how or why it happened, but I think it was related to failed page loads and going directly from the one favorite to the other. But either way, I believe it is a Firefox issue and not a SO issue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a firefox issue, not a SO issue. I have a "Google" folder in my bookmarks bar with links to my various Google services, and their icons seem to come and go at will - sometimes the default icon, sometimes a different one...

I also have the SO family linked in my bookmarks bar (Windows Firefox 3.5) and their icons haven't changed at all.